# Python: Convert a subset of a list into a dictionary by matching specific elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list in Python with each element being a single German word, e.g.:

```
my_list = [..., 'Stahl ', 'Stahl ', 'Die ', '*die ', 'Rheinhausener ', 'Rhein=Hausener ', 'Mittelstreckenraketen', 'Mittel=Strecken=Rakete', 'Mittel=strecken=Rakete', 'Mittels=trecken=Rakete',...]
```

In this list, compound nouns are immediately followed by their possible decompositions/splits (there can be an arbitrary number of decompositions/splits)

e.g. 'Mittelstreckenraketen' has 3 decompositions/splits:

> 'Mittel=Strecken=Rakete', 'Mittel=strecken=Rakete', 'Mittels=trecken=Rakete'

while 'Rheinhausener ' has only one:

> 'Rhein=Hausener '

The list is approximately 50,000 elements in length.

What I would like to do is extract only the compound nouns and their decompositions/splits, (discarding all other elements in the list) and read them into a dictionary with the compound noun as the key, and the decomposition/splits as values, e.g.:

```
my_dict = {...,'Rheinhausener ': ['Rhein=Hausener '], 'Mittelstreckenraketen': ['Mittel=Strecken=Rakete', 'Mittel=strecken=Rakete', 'Mittels=trecken=Rakete'],...}
```

Thereby discarding elements such as:

> 'Stahl ', 'Stahl ', 'Die ', '*die '

I was thinking of looping through the list and every time an element with one or more equals signs '=' appears, taking the preceding element and storing it as the key. But I'm too much of a Python newbie to figure out how to account for the arbitrary number of values for each dictionary entry; so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using a defaultdict. The defaultdict automatically creates an empty list if we attempt to access a key that doesn't exist.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [
    'Stahl ',
    'Stahl ',
    'Die ',
    '*die ',
    'Rheinhausener ',
    'Rhein=Hausener ',
    'Mittelstreckenraketen',
    'Mittel=Strecken=Rakete',
    'Mittel=strecken=Rakete',
    'Mittels=trecken=Rakete'
]

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

key = None
for word in my_list:
    if '=' in word:
        if key is None:
            print 'Error: No key found for', word
        my_dict[key].append(word)
    else:
        key = word

for key in my_dict:
    print '%r: %r' % (key, my_dict[key])
```

**output**

```
'Rheinhausener ': ['Rhein=Hausener ']
'Mittelstreckenraketen': ['Mittel=Strecken=Rakete', 'Mittel=strecken=Rakete', 'Mittels=trecken=Rakete']
```

Note that this code will not function correctly if the key element doesn't immediately precede the series of decompositions.

Answer (score 1):

You can using defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = ['Stahl ', 'Stahl ', 'Die ', '*die ', 'Rheinhausener ', 'Rhein=Hausener ', 'Mittelstreckenraketen', 'Mittel=Strecken=Rakete', 'Mittel=strecken=Rakete', 'Mittels=trecken=Rakete']

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

value = ''
for item in my_list:
  if '=' not in item:
    value = item
  else:
    my_dict[value].append(item)

print my_dict
```

which prints

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Rheinhausener ': ['Rhein=Hausener '], 'Mittelstreckenraketen': ['Mittel=Strecken=Rakete', 'Mittel=strecken=Rakete', 'Mittels=trecken=Rakete']})
```

It assumes the last item it saw without a '=' character in it, is the word we're trying to get the decomposition of.

Comment: Cheers! This does the job well enough! I can clean up the rest of my data using some regular expressions (it's quite irregular)